# How to get signed urls in java?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

Hii I am new to amazon s3 and cloudfront. I have task where I am uploading object to my bucket and sending cloudfront url to email. Sofar I have done uploading and downloading part successfully. For download my url looks like, "//cloudfront-domain/object-name". I want it to look like little complicated. I have been through documentation where it says I can add date expiration and it will also base64 the json policy and both will be available in url.
So as I am uploading object through java application I want to set policy to it and get signed url.
If you have sample codes around it please share.
Thanks.

Comment: I suggest you look at jets3t.

Answer (score 1):

> So as I am uploading object

Some people misunderstand this... signed URLs are not provided by the service.  You don't get them "as" you are uploading the object.  Signed URLs are generated by your code, with no interaction with the service at the time the signed URL is generated.

You typlically generate a signed URL at the same time you render the page where the signed URL will appear -- not just once, such as when you upload the object.  The latter is possible, but signed URLs have a finite lifetime and become invalid when you rotate your signing keys.

Here's the theory behind a signed URL.

The browser makes a request.  The service examines the policy document to verify that the parameters of the request actually match what the policy allows, then verifies the signature against the policy document, to see if it is authorized to honor the policy.  For a given policy document, there is only exactly one possible correct signature, so the service generates the signature that should have accompanied the request, to see if it matches.  If it does, the operation is permitted.  Since tampering with the policy would change the correct signature, signed URLs can't be tampered with.

The [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-signed-urls.html) explains how signed URLs work, as well as providing examples of how they are generated.  You can actually write your own code, to to this, if desires, because the entire signing process is documented.

Note that if you are using links in the form of `//dxxxexample.cloudfront.net/...` instead of `https://dxxxexample.cloudfront.net/...` then you need to generate the signed URL to expect `http*://dxxxexample...` rather than for `http://...` or `https://...` because otherwise, the same signed URL won't be valid for both HTTP and HTTPS.

Comment: Hii. Thanks for insight. Actually I have been through generating signed url process. Its still little hard to digest. But sooner I will get through.
So as we assign policy for object in json format in this way,

Comment: {
   "Statement": [
      {
         "Resource":"URL or stream name of the object",
         "Condition":{
            "DateLessThan":{"AWS:EpochTime":required ending date and time in Unix time format and UTC},
            "DateGreaterThan":{"AWS:EpochTime":optional beginning date and time in Unix time format and UTC},
            "IpAddress":{"AWS:SourceIp":"optional IP address"}
         }
      }
   ]
}

Comment: Do I need to create such json format and attach it with object before uploading?
And same json for url?

Comment: No.  These do not establish a policy for the *object*.  The policy applies to the actual *usage of the generated URL* itself.  You can generate an essentially infinite number of different signed URLs with different policies for one single object.  A single URL for multiple objects can also be created if you use a wildcard in the `Resource`, since CloudFront signed URLs support wildcards (unlike S3 signed URLs, which can only apply to a single object).

Comment: Hey you have any demo coding around it?
It will be really helpfull.

Comment: @ShubhamYedage click the link on the word "documentation" in the answer, then scroll all the way down.